# Proof of convergence of $L'\left(1,\chi\right)$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, characters

can someone give me a good reference for a clear proof of the convergence of $L'\left(1,\chi\right)$, $\chi$ real-valued, non-principal Dirichlet character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $L'(1,\chi)$ is a function, whereas "convergence" is a property of *series*. Do you have some particular series in mind? and some particular region where you would like to establish convergence?

Comment: $L'(1,\chi)$, according to my book (Apostol) is defined as 
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\inf \frac{\chi\left(n\right)\log\left(n\right)}{n}
$$
which means that the sum on the RHS must always be defined, so, forcing the language, always O(1), isn't it?
That's the proof I need.

Furthermore - the same book gives a proof of convergence, but I would like to see things from another perspective.

Comment: $\chi$ is periodic, and the sum over a period is zero. I suspect that's enough to put together some variant of the alternating series test to prove convergence. Apostol doesn't say anything?

Comment: $\chi$ itself is; but $\chi$ times something does not sum to zero over a period. If you have a character [1, -1, 1, -1], the sum would become 0-log(2)/2+log(3)/3-log(4)/4, on the first period, which is not null.

Comment: We have $\sum a_nb_n$, where $a_n$ is periodic and sums to zero over a period, while $b_n$ is positive and monotonically decreasing to zero. I'm suggesting that may be enough to ensure convergence, by some souped-up alternating series test.

Comment: See http://math.uga.edu/~pete/243series6.pdf for the kind of test I have in mind. It goes back to ... Dirichlet!

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Earth to user, come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

[Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) for convergence says if $a_1,a_2,\dots$ is a sequence of positive reals decreasing to zero, and $b_1,b_2,\dots$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $\bigl|\sum_1^nb_k\bigr|$ is bounded independent of $n$, then $\sum_1^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges.

Let $a_n=(1/n)\log n$ (strictly speaking, not decreasing, since $a_1=0$, but decreasing from some point on, which is good enough), let $b_n=\chi(n)$, then $b_n$ is periodic and sums to zero over a period, so the hypotheses of Dirichlet's test are met, so $\sum_1^{\infty}(1/n)\chi(n)\log n$ converges.

I don't know this for certain, but I suspect this is the problem that led Dirichlet to devise his test.